# PI decimal using Math.Round

Tags: c#, pi

I'm looking for an answer to the following:

#### Desired behaviour

Round the mathematical constant pi to 2 or 4 decimals.

#### Current code

I have tried the following:

```
Double piRounded;
piRounded = Math.Round.PI(4);
piRounded = Math.Round.PI(2);
```

#### Current result

This results in the following error:

> 'System.Math.Round(double)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context

Comment: Copy/paste you code directy in the post, do not upload a picture

Comment: Please post your code here, not a screenshot of it.

Comment: `Math.Round(Math.PI, 4);`

Comment: You have red squiggles under the `Round` method call. What does that error tell you? (

Comment: https://gyazo.com/278c15ccd0e612c19100548f2e0570a8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Math.Round in your code is being specified as a property, not a method invocation.

Place your parameters in the round function like `Math.Round(...)` - You will want to pass in the PI constant.

`Math.Round(Math.PI, 4)` (as stated in comments).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Math.Round(Math.PI, 2);
```

and

```
Math.Round(Math.PI, 4);
```

respectively

Comment: Thank you! i got it, sorry if i did some things wrong in the forum like the screenshot... Have a nice day!

Comment: Please mark as good answer =)